# rxjs and firebase TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx

I have an angular app that connects to firebase firestore as backend db.

I am attempting to write a generic function to get document snapshots from firestore.

Here is the function where I am getting my error:

```js
  /**
   * Get a 'listener' observable that subscribes to live document updates in the firestore db
   * @type the expected document type as interface
   * @param docPath path to document collection in firestore
   * @param docId id of document to get
   * @returns An Obseravble<DocumentSnapShot<Type>>
   */
  public watchDocument<T>(
    docPath: string,
    docId: string
  ): Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>> {
    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, docPath, docId) as DocumentReference<T>;
    return fromEventPattern<DocumentSnapshot<T>>(
      (handler) => onSnapshot<T>(docRef, handler),
      (handler, unsubscribe) => unsubscribe()
    );
  }
```

I also tried this version of the function:

```js
  public watchDocument<T>(
    docPath: string,
    docId: string
  ): Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>> {
    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, docPath, docId) as DocumentReference<T>;
    return new Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>>((subscriber) =>
      onSnapshot<T>(docRef, subscriber.next, subscriber.error)
    );
  }
```

BOTH version throw the following error on the **onSnapshot(docRef, handler)** call:

```
 TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
    at Array.push (<anonymous>)
    at ObserverProxy.subscribe...
```

This function is called from an NGRX effect.  If I only call one effect this function works.  However if this function is called by a previous action/effect then it fails with the error I quote above.

### EDIT: 1

I think what is happening is that NGRX is freezing something.  If I only call firestore functions everything works no matter the order.  the problem is that once I call any firebase authentication functions, like signInWithEmailAndPassword the following firestore functions will fail.

---

**QUESTION:**

I need help figuring out why this errors when chained with other actions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebaase but I can say this to ngrx: Ngrx objects are frozen by default. This is basically the core concept of immutability of ngrx objects. My assumption would be that the onSnapshot function writes something to the store and then tries to change the same object reference in the further process. Try setting the according flags documented in https://ngrx.io/api/store/RuntimeChecks#strictStateImmutability in order to pindown the issue.

Comment: @Loop thanks.  Ill take a look into those docs.  It turn out it is the firebase "auth" api that is trying to change the ngrx object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `onSnapshot` returns the unSubscribe method so it’s better to return unSubscription to the Observable like what you did.

I have Tested this with following changes:

```
watchDocument<T>(docPath: string,
    docId: string): Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>> {
    const docRef = doc(this.firestore, docPath, docId) as DocumentReference<T>;
    return new Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>>((subscriber) => {
      const subscription = onSnapshot<T>(docRef, snapshot => {
        subscriber.next(snapshot);
      });
      return () => {
        subscription();
      };
    });
  }
```

And getting document data as follows:

```
this.service.watchDocument(this.collectionName, this.documentId)
    .subscribe(document => {
      console.log(document.id, " ==> ", document.data())
    });
```

Now applying above logic with your `fromEventPattern` implementation will become:

```
watchDocumentWithEvent<T>(docPath: string,
    docId: string): Observable<DocumentSnapshot<T>> {
      const docRef = doc(this.firestore, docPath, docId) as DocumentReference<T>;
    return fromEventPattern<DocumentSnapshot<T>>(
      (handler) => {
        const subscription = onSnapshot<T>(docRef, handler);
        return () => subscription();
      },
      (subscription) => subscription()
    );
  }
```

As `fromEventPattern` returns the Observable of whatever returned as T or T[] so here, `subscription` is the `unsubscribe` function returned by the `onSnapshot` call , and it's passed to `fromEventPattern` as the second argument to allow `fromEventPattern` to cancel the subscription when the `Observable` is unsubscribed from.

Reference taken from [fromEventPattern](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEventPattern#fromeventpattern) and onSnapshot from the typescript vscode intellisense and [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener)

Comment: thanks.  it turned out to be firebase auth functions trying to change NgRx state objects in the store/state that are frozen.  However your code explanation really good so answer is yours.